# JS EventListener animationend firing too early

Tags: javascript

I need to change the width and height of an element using js with a smooth transition. My idea was to add a class to the element which makes the transition smooth, change the width and height, and once the transition is done, removing the class again. I use the following code:

```
    element.classList.add("smoothTransition")
    element.classList.toggle("fullscreen")
    element.addEventListener("webkitAnimationEnd", element.classList.remove("smoothTransition"));
    element.addEventListener("animationend", element.classList.remove("smoothTransition"));
```

Sadly no transition is happening. Without the eventListener the transition is happening. Also the eventListener does trigger, right after the transition starts.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is in your addEventListener:

```
element.addEventListener("webkitAnimationEnd", element.classList.remove("smoothTransition"));
element.addEventListener("animationend", element.classList.remove("smoothTransition"));
```

The second argument of [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) must be a a function and not the result of a function call (in your case **undefined**). Hence, change the previous lines to:

```
element.addEventListener("webkitAnimationEnd", function(e) {
    this.classList.remove("smoothTransition")
});
element.addEventListener("animationend", function(e) {
    this.classList.remove("smoothTransition")
});
```

You may consider to add your event listeners before transitions.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(e) {
  var element = document.querySelector('.box');
  element.addEventListener("webkitAnimationEnd", function(e) {
      this.classList.remove("smoothTransition");
      console.log('webkitAnimationEnd');
  });
  element.addEventListener("animationend", function(e) {
      this.classList.remove("smoothTransition");
      console.log('animationend');
  });
  element.classList.add("smoothTransition")
  element.classList.toggle("fullscreen")
});
```

```css
.box {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    background: red;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
@keyframes colorchange {
    0% { background: yellow }
    100% { background: blue }
}
.smoothTransition {
    animation: colorchange 2s;
}
.fullscreen {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: As the name suggests, this works for *animations* not transitions... but your solution works, ty :)